# Is equality in PA just an equivalence relation or it fulfills the substitution schemata of first order logic with equality?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, peano-axioms

I've noticed that the equality relation in [Peano arithmetic in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Formulation) and many other sites, is formalized simply as an *equivalence relation closed on the naturals*.

> Is there a proof that such formulation of PA would prove both [substitution schemata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms) of first order logic with equality?

Comment: It's worth noting that wikipedia provides *two* descriptions of PA. The one you're looking at is the historical one, and besides treating equality as an arbitrary equivalence relation has a second-order induction principle. [Later on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic) the article gives the first-order approach, in which (although this is annoyingly unstated) the underlying logic does have "proper equality."

Comment: all right even if so, lets say that we have a FIRST order theory with just equality treated as an equivalence class closed on naturals, would the theory prove the other axioms of equality theory?

Comment: Oh I wasn't saying the question was a bad one, I quite like it - I just wanted to clarify what was going on in the wikipedia article.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Is it sufficient to show substitution for the symbols $S$, $+$, and $\cdot$? I remember that in set theory where equality is not assumed, the Axiom of Extensionality asserts substitution for $\in$ under the equivalence relation "has the same elements".

Comment: @NoahSchweber, thanks for the clarification, the problem is that the article is vague as regards equality in the first order setting, I looked at the section of first order theory of arithmetic, it only mentions about the induction scheme and the addition and multiplication aspects, unfortunately it never mentions any change about the equality relation axiomatization, it says between two brackets (along with the usual axioms of equality) and one might take that to be the four ones mentioned in the article and not the ones conventionally held in first order logic with equality.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that it doesn't really matter.

At a syntactic, proof-theoretic level if you work in FOL with*out* equality, add a binary predicate symbol to your signature, state the **PA** axioms in terms of this binary predicate symbol, and then prove that this binary predicate symbol is reflexive and satisfies the substitution property, then you know it's consistent to instead take reflexivity and the substitution property as axiom( scheme)s. This is all FOL *with* equality is doing at the syntactic level.

The main differences then are 1) in one case a failure of reflexivity/substitutivity is an inconsistency whereas in the other case it just means our binary predicate symbol doesn't behave like equality, and 2) in one case a use of the substitution property is a single proof step and in the other case it is a reference to a meta-theorem and corresponds to a potentially quite large derivation. For the way most mathematicians work, these differences don't make any difference.

At a semantic level, the story is only slightly more interesting. The semantics of FOL *with* equality interprets the equality symbol as the equality of the meta-theory in which we're doing the semantics, ZFC say. A binary predicate symbol will just be interpreted as a binary relation. If that binary predicate symbol satisfies reflexivity and the substitution property, then we can show it is an equivalence relation and every *definable* subset of the domain is closed under this relation. That is, if $S$ is some definable subset of the domain and $\sim$ is the induced semantic equivalence relation, then $s\in S$ and $s\sim s'$ implies $s'\in S$. The upshot is if $D$ is the semantic domain of a model of the theory where equality is treated as an arbitrary relation with $\sim$ its induced semantic relation, then the quotient set $D/{\sim}$ is a model of the theory where equality is primitive. Therefore the extra models of the former don't change the validity relation.

However, the class of models are distinct in the semantic meta-theory. How these different classes of models relate to other objects of the semantic meta-theory or *non*-definable subsets is quite different. These are often unnatural questions to ask though. Most of the time it's simpler to consider the smaller class where the equivalence relation is required to be the meta-theory's equality.

You should prove the claims I'm making here yourself.

Comment: I realize now that I totally misinterpreted the question somehow, though I do implicitly answer it. The question this answer is addressing is something more like "Does it make a difference if we consider first-order **PA** where equality is logical equality or just a binary predicate symbol?" The "no" answer to this question does answer the OP's question (in the affirmative) though. The most direct answer would have been to do a syntactic proof by induction on the structure of formulas that the substitutivity holds for a binary predicate that satisfies the **PA** axioms.

Comment: What you need to do this is the substitution property for terms and atomic formulas. For terms, $0$ is handled by reflexivity, and $S$ is handled by axiom 7 but *only* because it's stated as an "if *and only if*". Substitutivity for atomic formulas means substitutitivity for the equality predicate itself which for one argument after using substitutibility for terms is just transitivity. Symmetry gives the other argument. From there the proof is generic.

Comment: but how you get substitution for arithmetical operators of addition and multiplication.